# Getting full matches of newline and tab groups with regex in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Code is supposed to extract the `\n\t` groups. It always starts with `\n` but `\t` can be 0 or more, with substrings in between them

```
def longestAbsolutePath(string):
...
paths[path] = r'dir\n\tsubdir1\n\t\tfile1'
special = re.search(r'(\\n(\\t)*)',paths[path])
print special
valid = True
if len(special.groups()) > 1:
    # do something
...
return longest
```

In the above test string, which is `dir\n\tsubdir1\n\t\tfile1`, I am expecting to get `\n\t` and `\n\t\t` in return.
I have tried `re.search` and `re.findall` but was not able to get 2 full matches, because it is returning `None` and `special` is printing:  `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'`.
How can I search the string in question to get 2 expected groups?

Comment: `...` has no place in. A minimal complete verifiable example http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `re.search` method will return the first match only, you need to use `re.findall` or `re.finditer`. Besides, the pattern is better written with a non-capturing group, `(?:...)`, since you do not use the value afterwards, and it messes up `re.findall` output if you use this method.

```
paths[path] = r'dir\n\tsubdir1\n\t\tfile1'
special = re.findall(r'\\n(?:\\t)*', paths[path])
if len(special) > 1:
    # do something
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ItfW8W)

Comment: thanks, why is that not a default. people usually want a full match

Comment: @RidhwaanShakeel It is actually a very nice feture. I have answered lots of questions and hear people complain there is no method like `re.findall` in their programming language.